# coldfusion spooler not working

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail, spooler

I have a coldfusion mail spooler locking up on me everytime I send out an email using this code:

```
<cfmail TO="xxxx@gmail.com" 
FROM="xxxx@xxxxxx.com" 
SUBJECT="Your Order!!!!!"  type="html">
hello
</cfmail>
```

Only way I can get this thing to email out of the spooler is to stop IIS and start IIS.
Then it flushes through.

If I use

```
<cfmail TO="xxxx@gmail.com" 
FROM="xxxx@xxxxxx.com" 
SUBJECT="Your Order!!!!!" spoolEnable="false" type="html">
hello
</cfmail>
```

Then the email goes straight through no problem, I would like to use the spooler since it has a less lag for the user.

What's going on with my coldfusion spooler??
I am running 9,0,0,251028 (standard)

BTW: I have tried doing (with no luck):

```
<cfset sFactory = CreateObject("java","coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory")>
<cfset MailSpoolService = sFactory.mailSpoolService>
<cfset MailSpoolService.stop()>
<cfset MailSpoolService.start()>
```

Comment: Your two code examples are identical, also why haven't you patched up to 901?

Comment: Sorry I fixed up the code example.  I will update soon, been busy with lots of other fires.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging first, like check [the mail logs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html) and/or [enable debugging ie `debug=true`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f8e.html).

Comment: I am getting (in coldfusion-out.log) 03/22 10:27:13 Information [scheduler-4] - Mail: 'Hello' From:'xxx@xxxxxxx.com' To:'xxxx@gmail.com' was successfully sent using 192.0.0.250

Comment: And I am lots of these in my mail.log - Next mail spool run in 15 seconds.

Comment: In cfadmin are you spooling to disk or memory?  When the spool clears, do the messages get delivered?  What SMTP are you using, local or remote?  If local, do you have mail relay setup?  I've personally had an issues of spool occasionally locking up once a month that resetting spoolservice or resetting CF fixed.. been having that since coldfusion 5 though.

Comment: Spooling to memory is only for enterprise, so I am spooling to disk.  Yes the messages get cleared from the spooler and delivered when IIS is turned off and back on.  Using a local exchange server.  No mail relay is setup.  I have tried resetting the CF server, no luck there.

Comment: I've never seen that issue.  While your mail is stuck, try to telnet to the mail server port 25 from your cf box.  Check and see what the response is.  Then turn off iis and try to telnet again to port 25 and check to see if the response is different.  Maybe you have 2 smtp instances that are fighting each other and one allows your relaying and one doesnt.... although I could be wrong and they may go to your undeliverable folder if that was the case.  what version of windows are you running and exchange?

Comment: When I log into telnet on port 25, I get the same message before and after I shut off IIS (World Wide Web Pub). 220 Exchange.xxxx.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sat, 23 Mar 2013
10:09:25 -0700

Comment: I am running 2008 R2 Standard & Exchange Server 2010

Comment: This all started happening after we made a domain name change.

Comment: I am leaning towards some misconfiguration in IIS when we switched it to a new domain.  Causing the spooler hangup.  When turning off IIS, the email goes through, so that tells me IIS is blocking the flow of things.

Comment: We switched the binding settings. I am thinking there might be something else in IIS that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be around since at least CF6.x and we haven't been able to find a permanent solution for it. Restarting the mail service is far from perfect.

Some have found that excluding the CF mail spooling directory from the virus scans helped, others say that sending emails with CFMAIL instead of with a cfscript did the job.

Here's a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079821/mail-mailspooler-spoollocktimeoutexception) and here's one from the [Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/556258)